# Data won't show on page when postback

Tags: knockout.js, breeze, durandal

With DurandalJS I have created a web application that shows specific data. This data is collected via BreezeJS and is called from the activated function of the DurandalJS framework.

When I first enter page A, all data is loaded correctly. When I then go to page B with a link on page A and then back from page B to A with a link I can see the data is loaded in my KnockoutJS observablearrays but it's not shown!

When there are multiple observablearrays on the page like A1, B2 and C3 on the very first load they are all loaded correctly when I surf on the web application and get back to the specific page with the observablearrays one moment A1 and C3 are loaded and B2 not! The other moment A1 and B2 and C3 is not shown. It's very random all!

When I hit CTRL + F5 everything is loaded correctly. Does this has anything to do with the framework of DurandalJS? Does anyone knows how to fix this problem?

What I tried so far:

- Using deferred
- Using deactivate so the property are cleaned in the right way so they can be filled in activate

Nothing so far.

Versions of the libraries:

- KnockoutJS: 2.3.0
- BreezeJS: 1.4.0
- DurandalJS: 1.2.0

These are the current versions of the libraries I have included. They were recently updated, hoping this would solve the problem but it didn't.

Here is my dataservice which is a Singleton:

```
var DataserviceClass = (function () {
    function DataserviceClass() {
        this._isSaving = false;
        this.suspendItemSave = false;
        this.ds = new breeze.DataService({
            serviceName: "api/data",
            hasServerMetadata: true
        });
        this.manager = new breeze.EntityManager({dataService: this.ds});
        this.metadataStore = this.manager.metadataStore;
        this.entityQuery = new breeze.EntityQuery();
        this.getMetadataStore = function () {
            return this.metadataStore;
        };

        this.getExportData = function() {
             return this.manager.exportEntities();
        };


        this.getAllRows = function (functionName, expand) {
            if (expand == null || expand == undefined) {
                this.entityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.from(functionName);
            } else {
                this.entityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.from(functionName).
                                                        expand(expand);
            }
            return this.manager.executeQuery(this.entityQuery);
        };
            
        this.getSpecificID = function (functionName, idName, id) {
            this.entityQuery = breeze.EntityQuery.from(functionName).where(idName, "==", id);
            return this.manager.executeQuery(this.entityQuery);
        };
            
    
        this.createT = function (initialValues, entity) {
            return this.manager.createEntity(entity, initialValues);
        };
            
        this.saveChanges = function (suppressLogIfNothingToSave) {
            if (this.manager.hasChanges()) {
                if (this._isSaving) {
                    setTimeout(this.saveChanges, 50);
                    return;
                }
                return this.manager.saveChanges().then(this.saveSucceeded).fail(this.saveFailed).fin(this.saveFinished);
            } else if (!suppressLogIfNothingToSave) {
            }
        };

        this.saveSucceeded = function (saveResult) {
            this._isSaving = false;
        };
        this.saveFailed = function (error) {
        };
        this.saveFinished = function () {
            this._isSaving = false;
        };
    }       
    var instance;
    return {
        getInstance: function() {
            if (instance == null) {
                instance = new DataserviceClass();
                instance.constructor = null;
            }
            return instance;
        }
    };
})();
```

On a page like estimate it's called as follows, this is the viewmodel:

```
define(function (require) {
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
        app = require('durandal/app'),
        system = require('durandal/system'),
        addmemo = require('viewmodels/modals/addMemo'),
        container = require('viewmodels/modals/container'),
        memo = require('viewmodels/modals/memo'), 
        dataservice = require('services/dataservice'),
        logger = require('services/logger'),
        addRepairOrderLine = require('viewmodels/modals/addRepairOrderLine'),
        repairorderline = require('viewmodels/modals/RepairOrderLine'),
        customerModal = require('viewmodels/modals/customer'),
        currentLoggedInEmployee = ko.observable(),
        memos = ko.observableArray([]),
        deferred = $.Deferred(),
        repairorderlines = ko.observableArray([]),
        tasksToMonitor = [],
        isLoading = ko.observable(false),
        suspendItemSave = false,
        rightParameters = true,
        notDone = true,
        hourscost = ko.observable(0.0),
        materialcost = ko.observable(0.0),
        grandtotal = ko.observable(0.0),
        currentRepairOrderID = -1,
        currentOrderID = -1,
        currentOrder = ko.observable(),
        currentRepairOrder = ko.observable(null),
        currentContainerID = -1,
        currentCustomer = ko.observable(null),
        currentBillingCustomer = ko.observable(null),
        currentContainer = ko.observable(null),
        showElementFade = function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).hide().slideDown(); },
        hideElementFade = function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).slideUp(function() { $(elem).remove(); }); };
        

    //This function is called ones, only when the page hasn't loaded yet!
    function init() {
        dataservice = DataserviceClass.getInstance();
       
        dataservice.getSpecificID('Employees', 'EmployeeID', 1).then(function (data) {
            currentLoggedInEmployee = data.results[0];
        }).fail(function(data) {
            logger.logError('Error fetching the current logged in employee!', null, null, true);
        });
    }
    init();
    
    return {
        displayName: 'Estimating page',
        router: router,
        currentCustomer: currentCustomer,
        currentContainer: currentContainer,
        currentRepairOrder: currentRepairOrder,
        currentBillingCustomer: currentBillingCustomer,
        memos: memos,
        repairorderlines: repairorderlines,
        isLoading: isLoading,
        hourscost: hourscost,
        materialcost: materialcost,
        grandtotal: grandtotal,
        activate: function (Context) { 
            currentRepairOrder(null);
            currentBillingCustomer(null);
            rightParameters = true;
            //also need to check if ids exist in DB!!
            if (!Context.hasOwnProperty("orderid") || isNaN(Context.orderid) ||
                !Context.hasOwnProperty("repairorderid") || isNaN(Context.repairorderid)) {
                rightParameters = false;
                system.log('Not all the right parameters!');
                router.navigateTo('#/error'); //eventueel parameters meegeven!
                return;
            }
            
            //set id's
            currentRepairOrderID = Context.repairorderid;
            currentOrderID = Context.orderid;
            tasksToMonitor = []; //empty the task function

          
            breeze.EntityQuery.from("Orders")  
                 .where("OrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.orderid))
                 .expand("Customer, Customer.PostCountry, Customer.VisitCountry, Container, Container.ContainerManufacturer, Container.ContainerType, Container.Owner")
                 .using(dataservice.manager)
                 .execute().then(function (data) {
                     if (data.results.length < 1) {
                         system.log('Not all the right parameters!');
                         rightParameters = false;
                         router.navigateTo('#/error'); //eventueel parameters meegeven!
                         return;
                     }
                     //extendItem(data.results[0]);
                     currentOrder(data.results[0]);
                    
                     var customer = data.results[0].Customer();
                     //extendItem(customer);
                     currentCustomer(customer);

                     var container = data.results[0].Container();
                     //extendItem(container);
                     currentContainer(container);
                 }).fail(function (data) {
                     logger.logError('Error fetching the current Order!', null, null, true);
                 }).fin(function() {
                     
                 });
            //In the future this will be calling the order 2

            
            breeze.EntityQuery.from("RepairOrders")
                 .where("RepairOrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.repairorderid))
                 .expand("BillingCustomer, BillingCustomer.PostCountry, BillingCustomer.VisitCountry")
                 .using(dataservice.manager)
                 .execute().then(function (data) {
                     currentRepairOrder(data.results[0]);
                     currentBillingCustomer(data.results[0].BillingCustomer());
                 }).fail(function (data) {
                     logger.logError('Error fetching current repairorder!', null, null, true);
                 }).fin(function() {
                     //first set the value to true (loading done)
                     //Call the global function to check each process
                     tasksToMonitor[0][1] = true;
                     checkTasks();
                 });

            //by adding this if statements the data is only loaded if it hasn't been loaded yet!
            //voor nu alle memos van alle medewerkers, later alleen die van betreffende?
           
            if (memos._latestValue.length == 0) {
                breeze.EntityQuery.from("Memos")
                    .where("RepairOrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.repairorderid))
                    //.expand("Customer, Container, Container.ContainerManufacturer, Container.ContainerType")
                    .expand("Employee")
                    .using(dataservice.manager)
                    .execute().then(function (data) {
                        data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                            extendItem(item);
                            memos.push(new memo(item));
                        });
                        system.log("Initialization succesfull!");
                        logger.logSuccess('Initialization succesfull', null, 'estimatepage', true);
                    }).fail(function (data) {
                        logger.logError('Error fetching memos!', null, null, true);
                    }).fin(function() {
                        tasksToMonitor[1][1] = true;
                        checkTasks();
                    });
            }

           
            if (repairorderlines._latestValue.length == 0) {
                breeze.EntityQuery.from("RepairOrderLines")
                     .where("RepairOrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.repairorderid))
                     .expand("Customer")
                     .using(dataservice.manager)
                     .execute().then(function (data) {
                         data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                             extendItem(item);
                             repairorderlines.push(new repairorderline(item));
                         });
                         updateFinance();
                         //
                     }).fail(function (data) {
                         logger.logError('Error fetching repairorderlines!', null, null, true);
                     }).fin(function() {
                         tasksToMonitor[2][1] = true;
                         checkTasks();
                        // deferred.resolve();
                     });
            }

            logger.log("Estimating page started!", null, "estimagepage", true);
            return deferred.promise();
            //return;
        },
        canDeactivate: function () {
            if (rightParameters && notDone) {
                return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page and stop estimating?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        deactivate: function() {
            //remove everything here! I mean remove the data in the models! Everything is already saved ;)
            memos.removeAll();
            repairorderlines.removeAll();

            currentRepairOrderID = -1;
            currentOrderID = -1;
            currentOrder(null);
            currentRepairOrder(null);
            currentContainerID = -1;
            currentCustomer(null);
            currentBillingCustomer(null); 
            currentContainer(null);
        },
        showCustomerModal: function(selectedCustomer,element) {
            app.showModal(new customerModal(selectedCustomer)).then(function () {

            }).fail(function() {

            });
        },
        showContainerModal: function() {
            app.showModal(new container(currentContainer, currentOrder())).then(function (result) {

            }).fail(function(result) {
                
            });
        },
        cancelEstimation: function() {
            app.showMessage('Do you want to delete this estimation?', 'Delete estimate', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                 
                }
                //else if no the user just clicked OK and everything is saved
            });
        },
        
        selectedRepairOrderLine: function (selectedRepairOrderLine, element) {
            app.showModal(selectedRepairOrderLine).then(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    app.showMessage('Do you want to delete this RepairOrderLine?', 'Delete RepairOrderLine', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                        if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                            repairorderlines.remove(selectedRepairOrderLine);
                            selectedRepairOrderLine.RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.entityAspect.setDeleted();
                            dataservice.saveChanges();
                            updateFinance(); //dont remove this one its called !
                            logger.logSuccess('Repairline deleted successfully', null, null, true);
                        }
                        //else if, no the user just clicked OK and everything is saved so also updatefinance is called a couple of line further
                    });
                }
                updateFinance(); //But we must update the finance because things could have been changed!
            }).fail(function () {
                logger.logError('Something went wrong selecting the memo!', null, 'estimatepage', true);
            });
        },
        selectedMemo: function (selectedMemo, element) {
                app.showMessage('Do you want to delete this memo?', 'Delete memo', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                    if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                        memos.remove(selectedMemo);
                        selectedMemo.MemoEntity._latestValue.entityAspect.setDeleted();
                        dataservice.saveChanges();
                    }
                    //else if no the user just clicked OK and everything is saved
            }).fail(function () {
                logger.logError('Something went wrong selecting the memo!', null, 'estimatepage', true);
            });
        },   
    };
});
```

This is the View that comes with it:

```
    <div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <!-- Estimate Information -->
        <!-- Estimate HEADER -->
        <div class="fiftypx" data-bind='with: currentContainer'>
            <span class="main_title">ESTIMATE</span>
            <span class="main_container_number" data-bind="text: ContainerNumber"></span>
        </div>
        <!-- Estimate Propertys -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span6">
                <fieldset>
                     <div class="estimate_info" data-bind="with: currentContainer">   
                        <span class="estimatepage_info_text">container number</span>   
                        <div data-bind="" class="estimate_info_DIV">
                            <span data-bind="text: ContainerNumber"></span>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    <div class="estimate_info" data-bind="with: currentBillingCustomer">   
                        <span class="estimatepage_info_text">billing customer</span>   
                        <div data-bind="click: $parent.showCustomerModal" class="estimate_info_DIV">
                            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>  
                        </div>
                        <button class="flatButtonSmall" data-bind="click: $parent.showCustomerModal">&#8250;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    <div class="estimate_info" data-bind='with: currentContainer'>   
                        <span class="estimatepage_info_text">equipment</span>   
                        <div data-bind="click: $parent.showContainerModal" class="estimate_info_DIV">
                            <span data-bind="text: ContainerNumber"></span>  
                        </div>
                        <button class="flatButtonSmall" data-bind="click: $parent.showContainerModal">&#8250;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
            <div class="span6">
                  <fieldset>
                    <!--<legend></legend> Deze niet toevoegen uitlijning is dan niet goed!-->
                    <div class="estimate_info" data-bind="with: currentRepairOrder">   
                        <span class="estimatepage_info_text">repair order</span>   
                        <div class="estimate_info_DIV">
                            <span data-bind="text: RepairOrderID"></span>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    <div class="estimate_info" data-bind='with: currentCustomer'>   
                        <span class="estimatepage_info_text">relation</span>   
                        <div data-bind="click: $parent.showCustomerModal" class="estimate_info_DIV">
                            <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>  
                        </div>
                        <button class="flatButtonSmall" data-bind="click: $parent.showCustomerModal">&#8250;</button>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                    <div class="estimate_info" data-bind="with: currentRepairOrder">   
                        <span class="estimatepage_info_text">creation date</span>  
                        <div class="estimate_info_DIV">
                            <span data-bind="text: Created().getDate() + '-' + (Created().getMonth() + 1) + '-' + Created().getFullYear()"></span>  
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                </fieldset>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6">
        <!-- Memo's -->
        <div class="fiftypx">
            <span class="main_title">MEMO'S</span>
            <button class="newButton" data-bind="click: addMemo">NEW</button>
            
            <button data-bind="click: doneEstimating" style="width: 130px;float: right;margin-right: 25px;" class="flatButtonBig" data-bind="">DONE</button>
            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
            <div>
                <div class="loader" data-bind="css: { active: isLoading }">
                    <i class="icon-spinner icon-2x icon-spin"></i>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <div id="memosTable">
            <table class="table" style="margin-left: -25px;">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th></th><th>date / user</th><th>memo</th><th></th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody data-bind="visible: memos().length > 0, foreach: memos">
                    <tr class="rowStyleFront">
                        <td style="width:25px;"></td>
                        <td style="width: 115px;">
                            <!-- date and user -->
                            <!-- text: MemoEntity._latestValue.CreationDate -->
                            <span class="upperSpan" data-bind="">Datum</span>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            <span class="lowerSpan" data-bind="text: MemoEntity._latestValue.Employee().Username()"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 300px;">
                            <!-- memo -->
                            <span style="display: inline; background-color: #f4931D; color: #FFFFFF; padding-right: 7px; padding-left: 5px;" class="upperSpan" data-bind="textToUpperCase: MemoEntity._latestValue.Type"></span>
                            <div style="clear: both;"></div>
                            <span style="margin-top: 20px; width: inherit;" class="lowerSpan" data-bind="text: MemoEntity._latestValue.Description"></span>
                        </td>
                        <td style="width: 50px;"><button data-bind="click: $parent.selectedMemo" style="float: right;" class="flatButtonBig" data-bind="">X</button></td>
                    </tr>              
                </tbody>
                <tbody data-bind="visible: memos().length == 0">
                    <tr class="rowStyleFront">
                        <td style="width:25px;"></td>
                        <td colspan="3">You haven't made any memo's yet.</td>
                    </tr>              
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span6">
        <!-- Add new repairline button and text -->
        <div class="fiftypx">
            <span class="main_title">REPAIRLINES</span>
            <button class="newButton" data-bind="click: addRepairline">NEW</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="span6" style="line-height: 50px;">
        <!-- totals! -->
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="span4">Hours cost: <span style="font-size: 16px;" data-bind="text: hourscost()"></span></div>
            <div class="span4">Materials: <span style="font-size: 16px;" data-bind="text: materialcost()"></span></div>
            <div class="span4">Total: <span style="font-size: 16px;" data-bind="text: grandtotal()"></span></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="row-fluid">
    <div class="span12">
        <!-- Table with all repairlines -->
        <table class="table" style="margin-left: -25px;">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th></th>
                    <th>Code</th>
                    <th>Mat</th>
                    <th>LOC</th>
                    <th>Rep</th>
                    <th>DAM</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>IsAgreement</th>
                    <th>Qty</th>
                    <th>Hours</th>
                    <th>Tariff</th>
                    <th>Costs</th>
                    <th>Lessee</th>
                    <th>Authorized</th>
                    <th>DoRepair</th>
                    <th><!-- Button --></th> <!-- 17 rijen -->
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody data-bind="visible: repairorderlines().length > 0, foreach: repairorderlines">
                <tr class="rowStyleFront">
                    <td style="width:25px;"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, text: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.Description"></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, text: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.InternalCode"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, text: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.MaterialCode"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, text: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.LocationCode"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, text: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.RepairCode"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, text: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.DamageCode"></td>
                    <td style="text-align: left;" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, text: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.Customer().Name()"></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.IsAgreement"/></td>
                    <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, numericText: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.Quantity"></td>
                    <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, numericText: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.Hours"></td>
                    <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, numericText: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.Tariff"></td>
                    <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine, numericText: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.Costs"></td>
                    <td data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine">-</td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.IsAuthorized"/></td>
                    <td><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: RepairOrderLineEntity._latestValue.DoRepair"/></td>
                    <td style="width: 50px;"><button class="flatButtonBig" data-bind="click: $parent.selectedRepairOrderLine">&#8250;</button></td>
                </tr>              
            </tbody>
            <tbody data-bind="visible: repairorderlines().length == 0">
                <tr class="rowStyleFront">
                    <td style="width:25px;"></td>
                    <td colspan="16">You haven't made any repairlines yet.</td>
                </tr>              
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah, I fixed it :)

Here's my explanation: per breeze function I have jQuery deferred object and I also have one global per page. In the activate function I call the when function of jQuery where all the functions are executed.

```
define(function (require) {
    var app = require('durandal/app'),
        suspendItemSave = false,
        system = require('durandal/system'),
        router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
        dataservice = require('services/dataservice'),
        logger = require('services/logger'),
        allCustomers = ko.observableArray(),
        allCountries = ko.observableArray(),
        allVats = ko.observableArray(),
        allCurrencys = ko.observableArray(),
        allContainerPropertySettings = ko.observableArray(),
        entireRepairlineLib = ko.observableArray(),
        repairAgreementsLib = ko.observableArray(),
        addVatModal = require('viewmodels/manager/addVat'),
        vatModal = require('viewmodels/manager/Vat'),
        addCurrencyModal = require('viewmodels/manager/addCurrency'),
        currencyModal = require('viewmodels/manager/currency'),
        addCountryModal = require('viewmodels/manager/addCountry'),
        countryModal = require('viewmodels/manager/country'),
        addContainerPropertySettingModal = require('viewmodels/manager/addContainerPropertySetting'),
        containerPropertySettingModal = require('viewmodels/manager/containerPropertySetting'),
        repairlineModal = require('viewmodels/manager/predefinedRepairline'),
        addPredefinedRepairlineModal = require('viewmodels/manager/addPredefinedRepairline'),
        repairAgreement = require('viewmodels/manager/repairAgreement'),
        deferred = $.Deferred();


    function getEntireRepairLib() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        breeze.EntityQuery.from("EntireRepairLineLib")
               .using(dataservice.manager)
               .execute().then(function (data) {
                   data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                       extendItem(item);
                       entireRepairlineLib.push(new repairlineModal(item));
                   });
                   system.log("Succesfully fetched EntireRepairLineLib");
                   d.resolve();
               }).fail(function (data) {

               });
        return d.promise();
    }

    function getRepairAgreements() {
        var d = $.Deferred();
        breeze.EntityQuery.from("RepairAgreements")
            .using(dataservice.manager)
            .execute().then(function(data) {
                data.results.forEach(function(item) {
                    extendItem(item);
                    repairAgreementsLib.push(new repairAgreement(item));
                });
                system.log("Succesfully fetched RepairAgreement");
                d.resolve();
            });
        return d.promise();
    }

    function init() {
        dataservice = DataserviceClass.getInstance(); //Get the dataservice instance.
    }

    init();
    return {
        router: router,
        displayName: 'Management page',
        allCustomers: allCustomers,
        allCountries: allCountries,
        allVats: allVats,
        allCurrencys: allCurrencys,
        allContainerPropertySettings: allContainerPropertySettings,
        entireRepairlineLib: entireRepairlineLib,
        repairAgreementsLib: repairAgreementsLib,
        activate: function () {       
            $.when(getEntireRepairLib(), getRepairAgreements(), etc, etc, .....)
               .done(function () {
                    deferred.resolve();
                    console.log("Done loading");
                    logger.log("Managementpage started!", null, null, true);
                    system.log("Managementpage started!");
               });                    
            return deferred.promise();
        },
        deactivate: function() {
            allCustomers([]);
            allCountries([]);
            allVats([]);
            allCurrencys([]);
            allContainerPropertySettings([]);
            entireRepairlineLib([]);
            repairAgreementsLib([]);
            deferred = $.Deferred(); //reset the deferred!
        }
    };
});
```

If there are any other (better) methods please let me now! I checked the console of Chrome and I see the logs are all executed before the binding! That was the problem!

Answer (score 0):

**Edit**

Alright, I am going to try to help you as best as possible and point a few things out along the way -

1. Open your project in Visual Studio or your editor of choice and do a 'Find', search the entire project, and anywhere you see 'latestValue' used in your viewModels or views, or really anywhere besides inside of your Knockout Library, you need to delete it.  If you need a value from a KO Observable or ObservableArray, use the getter function -

   ```
   if (memos._latestValue.length == 0)
   ```

should be

```
if (memos().length == 0)
```

I know that I have answered a question for you before and recommended this, I went back and double-checked it to be true, but seriously you need to do this, you are bypassing Knockout's core functionality by using _latestValue.

1. I checked a few of the ID observables that you have created and it seems you create them and set them to -1 but never use them - remove them all and if you need the ID of the currentContainer or other observable just call currentContainer().id().
2. When you are defining an observableArray you don't need to set it equal to nothing, nor do you need to call removeAll() when you are deactivating.

Defining a variable for the first time -

```
memos = ko.observableArray();
```

Setting a variable equal to nothing -

```
memos = ko.observableArray([]);
```

So when you are deactivating just set it equal to nothing instead of using removeAll().

That seems like a lot of work, but it's really not, and I have a feeling we will probably find why your view model is only loading half of the data the second time around in the process.

**Look here!!!**

In a few spots you are setting observables equal to data.results, which is good, but let's try cleaning them up a bit (I am not saying that there isn't a function named Customer on the first item in the array data.results, but if there isn't this will fix the issue) -

```
currentOrder(data.results[0]);

var customer = data.results[0].Customer();
//extendItem(customer);
currentCustomer(customer);

var container = data.results[0].Container();
//extendItem(container);
currentContainer(container);
```

Let's adjust that to -

```
currentOrder(data.results[0]);
currentCustomer(currentOrder().Customer());
currentContainer(currentOrder().Container());
```

**Your Deactivate function **

```
deactivate: function() {
            memos([]);
            repairorderlines([]);
            currentOrder(null);
            currentRepairOrder(null);
            currentCustomer(null);
            currentBillingCustomer(null); 
            currentContainer(null);
        },
```

**Original Answer**

Eliminate Breeze as the problem - if your Knockout observables are filled with data, then your queries are probably working as expected.

Eliminate Knockout as the problem - if your view model is populated with data, that is a good sign.  If the view itself is having binding issues, there are a few things you can try -

1. Look in the console - any data binds breaking?
2. Is your view handling cases where data may be loaded after the bindings are declared?

This will wait until an observable array is loaded before trying to display the data -

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: myArray"><li data-bind="text: name"></li></ul>
```

This will not -

```
<h1 data-bind="text: name" />
```

But you can debug that or prevent the binding from breaking like so -

```
<h1 data-bind="text: $data.name" />
```

Eliminate Durandal as the problem -

The framework of Durandal is quite stable and it is very doubtful that you have uncovered a bug that no one else has caught.  It is more likely that the first time you are visiting the page you are doing something differently than the second time you are visiting the page.  Without code we can't help to debug it any further.

One key note on Durandal - if your view model is a Singleton object and you are relying on some data to *always* be there you should consider using a constructor module.  More info @ http://durandaljs.com/documentation/Creating-A-Module/

Comment: I have added some code a complete page with viewmodel and view hope it helps. I also added some more text and explanation.

Comment: Alright I added a lot to the answer, I hope it helps you find the problem.

Comment: I have followed all your suggestions but non of them did the job :( anyother ideas?

Comment: Which observable or observable array isn't being loaded?  Will help to diagnose

Comment: That is very random, in debug I see the values in the viewmodel being loaded, I see via Fiddler2 they are correctly fetched. One time it's the estimatepropertys the other time it's the memo's that aren't being loaded. Sometimes none are shown while they are loaded in correctly :S

Comment: Are the bindings broken or its just acting pile it doesn't know that they changed?  Cam you put your edited code after suggestions above so I can see it more clearly?

Comment: The point is, nothing is changed I just switch between different pages:S, I post my code below in a new answer because I can't add anymore characters to my question

Comment: Look at the '*Your Deactivate function *' portion of my statement above, you will see one thing that you missed that may seem trivial but I think will make some progress for you.

Comment: @PK Kad nope that didn't do the trick either ;( I really don't understand what I'm doing wrong :S? 

One time I load the page all values are shown the other moment random values are shown, it's crazy :S, I see the values are loaded in, as I see in my console but they are not shown are I should say binded ;S

Comment: @PK Kad does it has anything to do with Caching? Because if I hit CTRL+ F5 all bindings are correct.

Answer (score 0):

Viewmodel:

```
 define(function (require) {
    var router = require('durandal/plugins/router'),
        app = require('durandal/app'),
        system = require('durandal/system'),
        addmemo = require('viewmodels/modals/addMemo'),
        container = require('viewmodels/modals/container'),
        memo = require('viewmodels/modals/memo'), //probably in the models folder but for now its okay
        dataservice = require('services/dataservice'),
        logger = require('services/logger'),
        addRepairOrderLine = require('viewmodels/modals/addRepairOrderLine'),
        repairorderline = require('viewmodels/modals/RepairOrderLine'),
        customerModal = require('viewmodels/modals/customer'),
        currentLoggedInEmployee = ko.observable(),
        memos = ko.observableArray(),
        deferred = $.Deferred(),
        repairorderlines = ko.observableArray(),
        tasksToMonitor = [],
        isLoading = ko.observable(false),
        suspendItemSave = false,
        rightParameters = true,
        notDone = true,
        hourscost = ko.observable(0.0),
        materialcost = ko.observable(0.0),
        grandtotal = ko.observable(0.0),
        currentRepairOrderID = -1,
        currentOrderID = -1,
        currentOrder = ko.observable(),
        currentRepairOrder = ko.observable(null),
        currentContainerID = -1,
        currentCustomer = ko.observable(null),
        currentBillingCustomer = ko.observable(null),
        currentContainer = ko.observable(null),
        showElementFade = function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).hide().slideDown(); },
        hideElementFade = function(elem) { if (elem.nodeType === 1) $(elem).slideUp(function() { $(elem).remove(); }); };

    function extendItem(itemToExtend) {
        if (itemToExtend.isEditing) return; // already extended

        itemToExtend.isEditing = ko.observable(false);
        //Deze functie wordt getriggerd zodra het aanpassen klaar is!

        // listen for changes with Breeze PropertyChanged event
        itemToExtend.entityAspect.propertyChanged.subscribe(function () {
            if (itemToExtend.propertyChangedPending || suspendItemSave) { return; }
            // throttle property changed response
            // allow time for other property changes (if any) to come through
            itemToExtend.propertyChangedPending = true;
            setTimeout(validateAndSaveModifiedItem, 10);

            function validateAndSaveModifiedItem() {
                if (itemToExtend.entityAspect.entityState.isModified()) {
                    if (itemToExtend.entityAspect.validateEntity()) {
                        dataservice.saveChanges();
                    } else { // errors
                        itemToExtend.isEditing(true); // go back to editing
                    }
                    //also update finance!
                    updateFinance();
                }
                itemToExtend.propertyChangedPending = false;
            }
        });
    }

    function updateFinance() {
        materialcost(0.0);
        hourscost(0.0);
        grandtotal(0.0);

        ko.utils.arrayForEach(repairorderlines(), function (line) {
            if (line.RepairOrderLineEntity().DoRepair()) {
                var materialcostTemp = (line.RepairOrderLineEntity().Costs() * line.RepairOrderLineEntity().Quantity()) + materialcost();
                materialcost(materialcostTemp);

                var hourscostTemp = (line.RepairOrderLineEntity().Tariff() * line.RepairOrderLineEntity().Hours()) + hourscost();
                hourscost(hourscostTemp);
            }
        });
        // materialcost = ko.observable(materialcost);
        // hourscost = ko.observable(hourscost);
        grandtotal(materialcost() + hourscost());

        //Showing the rounded numbers with the euro sign
        hourscost("€ " + parseFloat(Math.round(hourscost() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
        materialcost("€ " + parseFloat(Math.round(materialcost() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
        grandtotal("€ " + parseFloat(Math.round(grandtotal() * 100) / 100).toFixed(2));
    }
    //This function checks each task in the tasktomonitor array when they are all false (so loading is done)
    //The global iSloading is set to false, because loading is done:)
    function checkTasks() {
        var loadingDone = true;
        tasksToMonitor.forEach(function (item) {
            if (item[1] == false)
                loadingDone = false;
        });
        if (loadingDone) {
            deferred.resolve();
            isLoading(false);
        }
    }

    //This function is called ones, only when the page hasn't loaded yet!
    function init() {
        dataservice = DataserviceClass.getInstance();

        dataservice.getSpecificID('Employees', 'EmployeeID', 1).then(function (data) {
            currentLoggedInEmployee = data.results[0];
        }).fail(function(data) {
            logger.logError('Error fetching the current logged in employee!', null, null, true);
        });
    }
    init();

    return {
        displayName: 'Estimating page',
        router: router,
        currentCustomer: currentCustomer,
        currentContainer: currentContainer,
        currentRepairOrder: currentRepairOrder,
        currentBillingCustomer: currentBillingCustomer,
        memos: memos,
        repairorderlines: repairorderlines,
        isLoading: isLoading,
        hourscost: hourscost,
        materialcost: materialcost,
        grandtotal: grandtotal,
        activate: function (Context) { 
            currentRepairOrder(null);
            currentBillingCustomer(null);
            rightParameters = true;
            //also need to check if ids exist in DB!!
            if (!Context.hasOwnProperty("orderid") || isNaN(Context.orderid) ||
                !Context.hasOwnProperty("repairorderid") || isNaN(Context.repairorderid)) {
                rightParameters = false;
                system.log('Not all the right parameters!');
                router.navigateTo('#/error'); //eventueel parameters meegeven!
                return;
            }

            //set id's
            currentRepairOrderID = Context.repairorderid;
            currentOrderID = Context.orderid;
            tasksToMonitor = []; //empty the task function

            //fetching all necessary information
            //estimatepage/:orderid/:repairorderid
            //Fetch:
            /*
                billing customer
                owner container
                container number
                container propertys
                repair order 
                creation date of repairorder
                fetching memo's with repairorder
                fetching repairorderlines
            */

            //In this order the container fetch right away, thats one call less to the server
            breeze.EntityQuery.from("Orders")  
                 .where("OrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.orderid))
                 .expand("Customer, Customer.PostCountry, Customer.VisitCountry, Container, Container.ContainerManufacturer, Container.ContainerType, Container.Owner")
                 .using(dataservice.manager)
                 .execute().then(function (data) {
                     if (data.results.length < 1) {
                         system.log('Not all the right parameters!');
                         rightParameters = false;
                         router.navigateTo('#/error'); //eventueel parameters meegeven!
                         return;
                     }
                     currentOrder(data.results[0]);
                     currentCustomer(currentOrder().Customer());
                     currentContainer(currentOrder().Container());
                 }).fail(function (data) {
                     logger.logError('Error fetching the current Order!', null, null, true);
                 }).fin(function() {

                 });
            //In the future this will be calling the order 2

            tasksToMonitor.push(new Array('fetch_repairorders', false));
            breeze.EntityQuery.from("RepairOrders")
                 .where("RepairOrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.repairorderid))
                 .expand("BillingCustomer, BillingCustomer.PostCountry, BillingCustomer.VisitCountry")
                 .using(dataservice.manager)
                 .execute().then(function (data) {
                     currentRepairOrder(data.results[0]);
                     currentBillingCustomer(data.results[0].BillingCustomer());
                 }).fail(function (data) {
                     logger.logError('Error fetching current repairorder!', null, null, true);
                 }).fin(function() {
                     //first set the value to true (loading done)
                     //Call the global function to check each process
                     tasksToMonitor[0][1] = true;
                     checkTasks();
                 });

            //by adding this if statements the data is only loaded if it hasn't been loaded yet!
            //voor nu alle memos van alle medewerkers, later alleen die van betreffende?
            tasksToMonitor.push(new Array('fetch_memos', false));
            if (memos().length == 0) {
                breeze.EntityQuery.from("Memos")
                    .where("RepairOrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.repairorderid))
                    //.expand("Customer, Container, Container.ContainerManufacturer, Container.ContainerType")
                    .expand("Employee")
                    .using(dataservice.manager)
                    .execute().then(function (data) {
                        data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                            extendItem(item);
                            memos.push(new memo(item));
                        });
                        system.log("Initialization succesfull!");
                        logger.logSuccess('Initialization succesfull', null, 'estimatepage', true);
                    }).fail(function (data) {
                        logger.logError('Error fetching memos!', null, null, true);
                    }).fin(function() {
                        tasksToMonitor[1][1] = true;
                        checkTasks();
                    });
            }

            tasksToMonitor.push(new Array('fetch_repairorderlines', false));
            if (repairorderlines().length == 0) {
                breeze.EntityQuery.from("RepairOrderLines")
                     .where("RepairOrderID", "==", parseInt(Context.repairorderid))
                     .expand("Customer")
                     .using(dataservice.manager)
                     .execute().then(function (data) {
                         data.results.forEach(function (item) {
                             extendItem(item);
                             repairorderlines.push(new repairorderline(item));
                         });
                         updateFinance();
                         //
                     }).fail(function (data) {
                         logger.logError('Error fetching repairorderlines!', null, null, true);
                     }).fin(function() {
                         tasksToMonitor[2][1] = true;
                         checkTasks();
                        // deferred.resolve();
                     });
            }

            logger.log("Estimating page started!", null, "estimagepage", true);
            return deferred.promise();
            //return;
        },
        canDeactivate: function () {
            if (rightParameters && notDone) {
                return app.showMessage('Are you sure you want to leave this page and stop estimating?', 'Navigate', ['Yes', 'No']);
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        },
        deactivate: function() {
            //remove everything here! I mean remove the data in the models! Everything is already saved ;)
            memos.removeAll();
            repairorderlines.removeAll();

            currentRepairOrderID = -1;
            currentOrderID = -1;
            currentOrder(null);
            currentRepairOrder(null);
            currentContainerID = -1;
            currentCustomer(null);
            currentBillingCustomer(null); 
            currentContainer(null);
        },
        showCustomerModal: function(selectedCustomer,element) {
            app.showModal(new customerModal(selectedCustomer)).then(function () {

            }).fail(function() {

            });
        },
        showContainerModal: function() {
            app.showModal(new container(currentContainer, currentOrder())).then(function (result) {

            }).fail(function(result) {

            });
        },
        cancelEstimation: function() {
            app.showMessage('Do you want to delete this estimation?', 'Delete estimate', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                    //memos.remove(selectedMemo);
                    //selectedMemo.MemoEntity().entityAspect.setDeleted();
                   // dataservice.saveChanges();
                }
                //else if no the user just clicked OK and everything is saved
            });
        },
        addRepairline: function() {
            //logger.log('Clicked a button yeeeh', null, 'estimatepage', true);

            //Dit doen: addreapirline de repairline laten maken en de foto's
            //dan de gemaakte repairline teruggeven aan deze functie.
            var t = currentRepairOrder().ID();
            app.showModal(new addRepairOrderLine(currentRepairOrderID, currentCustomer,currentBillingCustomer)).then(function (result) {
                if (result != undefined) {
                    extendItem(result);
                    repairorderlines.push(new repairorderline(result));
                    updateFinance();
                }
            }).fail(function(result) {
                logger.logError('Error fetching result adding repairline', null, null, true);
            });
        },
        addMemo: function() {
            app.showModal(new addmemo(currentLoggedInEmployee)).then(function (result) {
                if (result != undefined) {                
                    var memoN = dataservice.createT({
                        Description: result[0].Description,
                        EmployeeID: result[0].EmployeeID, //Dit moet echt de employee zelf zijn niet zijn ID!!!
                        Type: result[0].Type,
                        RepairOrderID: currentRepairOrderID
                    }, 'tblMemo');

                    if (memoN.entityAspect.validateEntity()) {
                        extendItem(memoN);
                        memos.push(new memo(memoN)); 
                        dataservice.saveChanges();
                        logger.logSuccess('Memo added succesfully!', null, null, true);
                    }
                }
            }).fail(function(result) {
                logger.logError('Something went wrong adding a memo!', null, 'estimatepage', true);
            });
        },
        selectedRepairOrderLine: function (selectedRepairOrderLine, element) {
            app.showModal(selectedRepairOrderLine).then(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    app.showMessage('Do you want to delete this RepairOrderLine?', 'Delete RepairOrderLine', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                        if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                            repairorderlines.remove(selectedRepairOrderLine);
                            selectedRepairOrderLine.RepairOrderLineEntity().entityAspect.setDeleted();
                            dataservice.saveChanges();
                            updateFinance(); //dont remove this one its called !
                            logger.logSuccess('Repairline deleted successfully', null, null, true);
                        }
                        //else if, no the user just clicked OK and everything is saved so also updatefinance is called a couple of line further
                    });
                }
                updateFinance(); //But we must update the finance because things could have been changed!
            }).fail(function () {
                logger.logError('Something went wrong selecting the memo!', null, 'estimatepage', true);
            });
        },
        selectedMemo: function (selectedMemo, element) {
                app.showMessage('Do you want to delete this memo?', 'Delete memo', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                    if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                        memos.remove(selectedMemo);
                        selectedMemo.MemoEntity().entityAspect.setDeleted();
                        dataservice.saveChanges();
                    }
                    //else if no the user just clicked OK and everything is saved
            }).fail(function () {
                logger.logError('Something went wrong selecting the memo!', null, 'estimatepage', true);
            });
        },
        /*
        selectedMemo: function (selectedMemo, element) {
            app.showModal(selectedMemo).then(function (result) {
                if (result) {
                    app.showMessage('Do you want to delete this memo?', 'Delete memo', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                        if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                            memos.remove(selectedMemo);
                            selectedMemo.MemoEntity().entityAspect.setDeleted();
                            dataservice.saveChanges();
                        }
                        //else if no the user just clicked OK and everything is saved
                    });
                }
            }).fail(function() {
                logger.logError('Something went wrong selecting the memo!', null, 'estimatepage', true);
            });          
        },
        */
        /*
        getUser: function (userId) {
            var t;
            dataservice.getSpecificID('AllEmployees', 'EmployeeID', userId).then(function (data) {
                t = "Dit is mijn tekst: " + data.results[0].Username();
                return t;
            });
            return t;
        },*/
        removeMemos: function () {
            var memoSelectedToBeRemoved = false;

            $.each(memos(), function (i, l) {
                if (l.markedForDeletion()) {
                    memoSelectedToBeRemoved = true;
                }
            });

            if (memoSelectedToBeRemoved == false) {
                app.showMessage('No memos selected!','No memos');
                return; //No memos selected to be deleted!
            }

            app.showMessage('Do you want to delete the selected memos?', 'Delete memos', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function(resultMessageBox) {
                if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                    //create a temp new KOarray
                    //for each memo that is not to be deleted put them in a new list
                    //At the end remove all memos from memos. then push all memos from the temp list to memos.
                    var newMemoList = ko.observableArray([]);
                    var numberOfMemos = memos().length;
                    $.each(memos(), function (i, l) {
                        if (!l.markedForDeletion()) {
                            newMemoList.push(l);
                        } else {
                            l.MemoEntity().entityAspect.setDeleted();
                        }
                    });
                    dataservice.saveChanges();
                    memos.removeAll();

                    $.each(newMemoList(), function (i, l) {
                        memos.push(l);
                    });
                    logger.logSuccess('A total of: ' + (numberOfMemos - newMemoList().length) + ' memos have been removed.', null, null, true);
                }
            });
        },
        doneEstimating: function () {
            if (repairorderlines().length < 1) {
                app.showMessage('No repairlines added yet!', 'Estimate cannot be ready');
                return;
            }

            app.showMessage('Are you sure you are done estimating?', 'Estimate done', ['Yes', 'No']).then(function (resultMessageBox) {
                if (resultMessageBox == "Yes") {
                    //sent repairOrderID to server
                    //server fetch all data like repairorderlines etc.
                    //server sents mail to user
                    notDone = false;
                    router.navigateTo('startingpage');
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: When I check my console in the browser like Chrome or IE I see the values are there :S

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the file: viewModelBinder.js part of the DurandalJS framework takes care of the bindings.

```
    define(['./system'], function (system) {
    var viewModelBinder;
    var insufficientInfoMessage = 'Insufficient Information to Bind';
    var unexpectedViewMessage = 'Unexpected View Type';

    function doBind(obj, view, action) {
        if (!view || !obj) {
            if (viewModelBinder.throwOnErrors) {
                throw new Error(insufficientInfoMessage);
            } else {
                system.log(insufficientInfoMessage, view, obj);
            }
            return;
        }

        if (!view.getAttribute) {
            if (viewModelBinder.throwOnErrors) {
                throw new Error(unexpectedViewMessage);
            } else {
                system.log(unexpectedViewMessage, view, obj);
            }
            return;
        }

        var viewName = view.getAttribute('data-view');

        try {
            system.log('Binding', viewName, obj);

            viewModelBinder.beforeBind(obj, view);
            action();
            viewModelBinder.afterBind(obj, view);
        } catch (e) {
            if (viewModelBinder.throwOnErrors) {
                throw new Error(e.message + ';\nView: ' + viewName + ";\nModuleId: " + system.getModuleId(obj));
            } else {
                system.log(e.message, viewName, obj);
            }
        }
    }

    return viewModelBinder = {
        beforeBind: system.noop,
        afterBind:system.noop,
        bindContext: function(bindingContext, view, obj) {
            if (obj) {
                bindingContext = bindingContext.createChildContext(obj);
            }

            doBind(bindingContext, view, function () {
                if (obj && obj.beforeBind) {
                    obj.beforeBind(view);
                }

                ko.applyBindings(bindingContext, view);

                if (obj && obj.afterBind) {
                    obj.afterBind(view);
                }
            });
        },
        bind: function(obj, view) {
            doBind(obj, view, function () {
                if (obj.beforeBind) {
                    obj.beforeBind(view);
                }

                ko.applyBindings(obj, view);

                console.log(obj);

                if (obj.afterBind) {
                    obj.afterBind(view);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

When I debug I see the values that are binded. And then I see somevalues are indeed sometimes empty. So they are empty when they are binded. But they are not re-bind when I enter a completely new value.

How can I solve this? That the page is only binded when ALL the async calls to breeze are ready and the neccassery property's are filled?